# How do I add blank lines into a Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, line-breaks

I am working on a website that has different features a person can order. I would like to put a bootstrap glyphicon next to those features and then when the user rolls over the glyphicon a tooltip would show what was included in those features.
I am having trouble introducing blank lines into the tooltip. I've tried \n 
 and &#013 (with the pre-wrap command in my css) Here is the portion of my code cooresponding to the tooltip.

```
<br/>2 Printed Sheets
  <a href="#" data-toggle = "tooltip" title = 
    "One printed sheet can include &#013;1 8 x 10 &#013;2 5 x 7 &#013;2 4 x 6 &#013;4 3.5 x 5 &#013;9 wallet photos">
    <span style = "color:white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign white"></span>
  </a>
```

I'm also using the following JQuery command:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
  });
</script>
```

How can I put blank lines where the &#013 is. It is worth noting that before I added in the JQuery section the blank lines did work properly, but when I added in the JQuery section the line breaks were removed.

Comment: Check the example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the html to true and use `<br>` in title attribute, or you can also set the data attribute `data-html="true"`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        html:"true"
    });   
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h1>Tooltip below</h1>
          <a href="#" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-placement = "down" title="One printed sheet can include &#013;<br></a>1 8 x 10 &#013;<br></a>2 5 x 7 &#013;<br></a>2 4 x 6 &#013;<br></a>4 3.5 x 5 &#013;<br></a>9 wallet photos">
          <span style = "color:white" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign white"></span>Tooltip
        </a>
```

Demo: https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/BE2dE

Answer (score 1):

You could add  `<br />`

```
   title="1st line of text <br> 2nd line of text"

  title = 
        "One printed sheet can include <br>
            1 8 x 10 <br>
            2 5 x 7 <br>
            2 4 x 6 <br>
            4 3.5 x 5 <br>
            9 wallet photos"
```

Answer (score 0):

add data-html="true" attribute next to data-toggle and then you can use breakrow tags inside the title anywhere to implement new line